# Being a member of a Facebook group and THEN to be able to register and login to a website. How to do it?

Tags: facebook-authentication, user-registration

I've been searching the internet for a while to come up with a solution for the issue of logging in to a website with the support of Facebook account. The case study is as follows:

1. I have a website which provides course materials to my students in a class.
2. I have created a Facebook Group - private - to keep in touch with only students who are registered for the course.
3. I'd like to allow students to use their Facebook account (whom are member of that particular group) to be able to login to that website. This means public users with Facebook account which are not a member of that particular Facebook group should not able to login to that website.
4. I've been using classic ASP for the development of that website, which provides teaching materials.

Comment: So, what are you teaching your students by using Classic ASP for development?

Answer (score 1):

For checking "(facebook) user" -> "group" it makes me think of [facebook graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

After geting an access_token form user,
you could get the information of which groups they had join from graph API like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?access_token=[access_token]
```

the result would be something like this (in JSON)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "version": 1, 
      "name": "GROUP_NAME", 
      "id": "GROUP_ID", 
      "bookmark_order": 1
    }, 
    {
      "version": 1, 
      "name": "GROUP_NAME2", 
      "id": "GROUP_ID2", 
      "administrator": true, 
      "bookmark_order": 2
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000"
  }
}
```

I think checking group id would work for "user" -> "group."

You will not need to storage group member list on your server by this way, and if they leave (or banned by) the group will immediately stop the access. (since ID in JSON list will not match your checking anymore)

But you will need to:

- Need to create an app "Canvas Page" on facebook for getting access_token from user
- Getting json string from http"s" by ASP (sorry I have not use ASP before but I got some trouble when using PHP to achieve this, it surely spent me "some" time)

Comment: Dear @Crow, Thank you for the reply. I wasn't aware of the reply till now. I will try to implement it and get back to you again of the outcome. Thanks again. Regards, Alan.